# Javascript object property value as expression does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, expression

I am new to JS, I made some investigation but couldn't find a solution. Forgive me if it is a duplicate.

Context: I have thousands of objects, most of them the same properties. In the javascript, I get all the properties of objects and format them to show in html. Since some objects doesn't have all the properties, i get undefined value. To solve this problem, I wrote this code:

```
var twitter = $.map(tweets, function(obj, index) {
                  return {                      
                     Format: ((typeof obj.VideographyFeatures.Format === "undefined") ? "N/A" : obj.VideographyFeatures.Format)
                  };
               });
```

But it doesn't work. For the objects which don't have "VideographyFeatures" property, I still get the following error.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Format' of undefined".

My aim is to get:

```
{
Format: "N/A"
};
```

Comment: Yes, you cannot test whether `.Format` is `undefined` if `.VideographyFeatures` is `undefined`. You first have to check whether `obj.VideographyFeatures` is defined.

Comment: Thank you, for the fast answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `obj.VideographyFeatures` is undefined, you cannot get its `Format` property to pass to the `typeof` expression.

You need to check `typeof obj.VideographyFeatures`.